# Undefined error in jquery tokeninput

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

jQuery tokeninput returns *null* value. when I submit the form the $_POST[] array is empty.

In the [demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html) when I click submit button it alert :"would submit:" and the values. I did the same in mine and it alert : `"would submit: undefined"`.

my form.html :

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">

                            <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-2">Title(s) :</label>
                                <input name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
                                <input type="button" value="Submit" />
                                <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#title").tokenInput("gethint.php", {
                theme: "facebook",
                hintText: "Begin typing title ...",
                noResultsText: "No titlesfound",
                propertyToSearch: "title",
                tokenValue: "'id'",
                tokenDelimiter: ","
            });
        });
        </script>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

process.php :

```
<?php
$titles = $_POST["title"];
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
print_r($names);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `input[type=text]`elements in your html as specified here:

```
alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
```

Change your html to:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
```

Comment: WoW, How did I miss that ? :) Thank you

Comment: @DrZIZO - its easily done ;) if it works for you could you mark it as the answer?

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes before accepting your answer